# How to retrieve field "cotacaoCompra" inside the Json using retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am total noob inside the Android.
Now i am using  Retrofit to request a field in API, but this API is complex for a simple request. I only want a value of field called "cotacaoCompra", but everytime i send a request, the return is null. Please, if you know how to help me, i will be very grateful.

API link
http://twixar.me/rFNK

My base Retrofit

```java
retrofitBrita = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/PTAX/versao/v1/odata/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
recuperarMoedasRetrofit();
```

My Getters and Setters

```java
public class Brita {
    private String cotacaoCompra;
    private String cotacaoVenda;
    public String getCotacaoCompra() {
        return cotacaoCompra;
    }
    public void setCotacaoCompra(String cotacaoCompra) {
        this.cotacaoCompra = cotacaoCompra;
    }
    public String getCotacaoVenda() {
        return cotacaoVenda;
    }
    public void setCotacaoVenda(String cotacaoVenda) {
        this.cotacaoVenda = cotacaoVenda;
    }
}
```

My Interface

```java
@GET("CotacaoDolarDia(dataCotacao=@dataCotacao)?@dataCotacao='04-26-2019'&$top=1&$format=json&$select=cotacaoCompra,cotacaoVenda,dataHoraCotacao")
    Call<Brita> recuperarBitcoin();
```

My enqueue

```java
call.enqueue(new Callback<Brita>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(Call<Brita> call, Response<Brita> response) {
                 Brita brita = response.body();
                 if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                     login_login.setText(brita.getCotacaoCompra());
                 }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Retrofit with Gson, you usually replicate the json in java models. You've done this properly with `Brita`, but that's just an element inside the `value` array:

```
{  
  "cotacaoCompra":3.9347,
  "cotacaoVenda":3.9353,
  "dataHoraCotacao":"2019-04-26 13:11:30.05"
}
```

*(Actually, if you're just interested in `cotacaoCompra` you can simply remove all other fields from `Brita` and just keep `cotacaoCompra`.)*

The problem with this is that Gson will try to deserialize a json that matches `Brita`, which is not the case. Your json is an object, with a field called `value`, which is an array of `Brita` objects. So let's replicate this in Java POJOs:

```
class BritaResponse {
  @SerializedName("value")
  private List<Brita> value;
  // getters and setters
}
```

`BritaResponse` is an object, which has a list of `Brita` objects.

Now you can define the Retrofit call like:

```
@GET("CotacaoDolarDia(dataCotacao=@dataCotacao)?@dataCotacao='04-26-2019'&$top=1&$format=json&$select=cotacaoCompra,cotacaoVenda,dataHoraCotacao")
Call<BritaResponse> recuperarBitcoin();
```

This will now return a `BritaResponse`. You will have to access the field `value` and then the first element of the array in the retrofit response.

**Edit**

To answer your comments. `BritaResponse` is a new class. To access the first item, inside `onResponse` you just need to do something like:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<BritaResponse>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<BritaResponse> call, Response<BritaResponse> response) {
             BritaResponse britaResponse = response.body();
             if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                 login_login.setText(
                    britaResponse.getValue().get(0).getCotacaoCompra());
             }
         }
```

Comment: Thks so much!! But I'm in doubt if this Class BritaResponse is a new class or i need to modify my old class Brita.

Comment: Another question, how can i access the first item of this array? In my enqueue? and how? Sorry for my basic questions, but i really don't know.